# Will a .com SSL certificate cover a redirecting .com.ar domain?

Tags: redirects, apache, https, url-rewriting

we have a website with 2 different domains:

`www.example.com` or `example.com`

and `www.example.com.ar` or `example.com.ar`

I want all requests redirected to `www.example.com`.

I know I have to create two virtual hosts in Apache and in the `.htaccess` file for `.com.ar` site put the rewrite rule (as explained here [I have domain.com and domain.org to the same site, should I use redirects to avoid duplicate content](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16187/i-have-domain-com-and-domain-org-to-the-same-site-should-i-use-redirects-to-avo))

My question is: we have a wildcard SSL certificate for `.com` domain. Is it possible to redirect HTTPS requests for `www.example.com.ar` and `example.com.ar` to the `.com` site? Or I should get another SSL certificate for `.com.ar` domain?

Comment: Although it is a bit of work to set up, you can use CloudFlare to redirect your alternate domain with HTTPS for free.   I've started using them for some of my alternate domains because it is easier than obtaining and managing the certificates on my own.  See [these instructions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/113180/how-to-avoid-ssl-warnings-about-certificate-not-for-the-current-site-when-redire/129449#129449)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to redirect HTTPS requests for `www.example.com.ar` and `example.com.ar` to `.com` site? Or I should get another SSL certificate for `.com.ar` domain?

You'll need an SSL cert that covers `.com.ar`.

> I know I have to create two virtual hosts in apache and in the htaccess file for .com.ar site put the rewrite rule

If you are creating virtual hosts then you don't need `.htaccess` or any "rewrite rule". The simpler mod_alias `Redirect` is all that's required. (Preferably, you'll use *four* virtual hosts - one for each hostname.)

Comment: One could use fewer than four virtual hosts with `ServerAlias` and SAN certificates.  If you could get a SAN cert that covered all the alternate domains and subdomains, the redirects could easily be done in a single virtual host.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, you could and that may indeed be preferable in some cases. However, I was suggesting multiple vHosts to avoid mod_rewrite (and easier implementation of HSTS) - which would generally be considered simpler and more performant.